# How can i make an enemy face player as well as be parallel to the ground in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

Im tried to make enemy face player by passing `transform.LookAt(target)` but with this i cannot achieve the parallel rotation to the ground.

I added a raycast downward for the enemy to find out the angle of the ground but im not sure how to add that rotation with the enemy looking at the player rotation together

```
    void Groundangle()
    {
        Vector3 Current_Rotation = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;
        RaycastHit Hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(EnemyEyes.position, EnemyEyes.TransformDirection(Vector3.down), out Hit, Mathf.Infinity, groundDetct))
        {
            float angle = Vector3.Angle(transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.down), Hit.normal) - 180f;
            Debug.Log(angle);
            Quaternion newrot = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(Current_Rotation.x, angle, Current_Rotation.z));
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, newrot, Time.deltaTime);            
        }
    }
```

This here works fine with the **look at player** part but i dont know how to implement ground rotation with the forward rotation.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using

```
trasform.LookAt(target);

if (Physics.Raycast(EnemyEyes.position, -EnemyEyes.up, out var hit, Mathf.Infinity, groundDetct))
{
    transform.up = hit.normal;
}
```

This will first rotate the object to face directly with it's forward vector towards the target and then rotate it again slightly to match the up vector according to the ground.

---

Or as alternative pretty similar you could take the direction

```
Vector3 Current_Rotation = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;
```

and in case of a ground hit map it onto the plane of the ground like

```
if (Physics.Raycast(EnemyEyes.position, -EnemyEyes.up, out var hit, Mathf.Infinity, groundDetct))
{
    Current_Rotation = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(Current_Rotation, hit.normal).normalized;
}

transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Current_Rotation);
```

then you can still use `Slerp`

Comment: Your solution runs perfectly on upward slops but when it comes to downward slops the enemy starts resetting itself to 0. Do you have any idea on why is that happening?

Comment: ```    void Groundangle()
    {
        Vector3 Current_Rotation = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;
        if (Physics.Raycast(EnemyEyes.position, -EnemyEyes.up, out var Hit, Mathf.Infinity, groundDetct))
        {
            Current_Rotation = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(Current_Rotation, Hit.normal).normalized;

            
        }
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(Current_Rotation), Time.deltaTime * 4f);
    }
```
here is the code now
sorry about the mess of a code idk how to fix that